# Swift 5/iOS 13+ – Google Cloud Functions won't let me add a value

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Cloud Functions (GCF) to schedule posts on Instagram (an app similar to Hootsuite). I just integrated local notifications and I want to add the ID (generated automatically by my "notificationManager") to the post (data sent to Google Cloud).

Basically, the way that it works is the app sends the data to GCF and GCF is responsible for adding the elements to Firestore Database, but after many failed attempts, I cannot seem to figure out how to add an additional value. My goal is to add the element "notificationIdentifier", but for some reason, GCF won't register it (I can't even see it in the logs!).

Here's what's in GCF:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
/* eslint-disable */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");
const FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION = "v11.0";
const FACEBOOK_APP_ID = Undisclosed APP_ID;
const FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = Undisclosed APP_SECRET;
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();
const main = express();
const db = admin.firestore();

/**
 * publish Instagram Media Object.
 * @param {string} container_id instagram media object creation id.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @return {Promise} Returns container status
 */
async function getContainerStatus(container_id, accessToken) {
  let status = "IN PROGRESS";
  let response;
  try {
    response = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/${container_id}`,
      {
        params: {
          access_token: accessToken,
          fields: "status_code",
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return "ERROR";
  }
  // console.log(response.data.status_code, "status");
  status = response.data.status_code;
  return status;
}

/**
 * Get LongLive Token Expire in 60 days.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @return {Promise} Return Long Live token.
 */
function getLongLiveToken(accessToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/oauth/access_token`,
        {
          params: {
            grant_type: "fb_exchange_token",
            client_id: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            client_secret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
            fb_exchange_token: accessToken,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response.data.access_token);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

/**
 * Get Facebook Pages.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @return {Promise} Returns the facebook pages result.
 */
function getFacebookPages(accessToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/me/accounts`,
        {
          params: {
            access_token: accessToken,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data.data;
        resolve(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

/**
 * Get Instagram Account From Facebook Pages.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @param {string} pageId Page ID.
 * @return {Promise} Returns the Instagram Account Id.
 */
function getInstagramAccountId(accessToken, pageId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/${pageId}`,
        {
          params: {
            access_token: accessToken,
            fields: "instagram_business_account",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.instagram_business_account) {
          resolve({
            id: response.data.instagram_business_account.id,
          });
        } else {
          resolve({ error: "No instagram Business Account" });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

/**
 * Get Facebook Profile.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @return {Promise} Returns the Facebook Account Profile.
 */
function getFacebookProfile(accessToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/me`, {
        params: {
          access_token: accessToken,
          fields: "name,picture,email",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        resolve({
          picture: response.data.picture.data.url,
          name: response.data.name,
          email: response.data.email,
          facebookUserId: response.data.id,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

/**
 * Get Instagram Profile.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @param {string} instagramAccountId Instagram Account ID.
 * @return {Promise} Returns the Instagram Account Profile.
 */
function getInstagramProfile(accessToken, instagramAccountId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/${instagramAccountId}`,
        {
          params: {
            access_token: accessToken,
            fields: "name,username,profile_picture_url",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

/**
 * Create Instagram Media Object.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @param {string} instagramAccountId Instagram Account ID.
 * @param {string} caption caption.
 * @param {string} mediaType Instagram Account ID.
 * @param {string} mediaUrl media url
 * @return {Promise} Returns created Instagram Media ID.
 */
function createInstagramMedia(
  accessToken,
  instagramAccountId,
  caption,
  mediaType,
  mediaUrl,
  tags,
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      access_token: accessToken,
      caption: caption,
    };
    let user_tags = [];
    if(tags != null) {
      for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        const user_tag = {
          "username": tags[i],
          "x": Math.random(),
          "y": Math.random()
        }
        user_tags.push(user_tag);
      }
    }
    if (mediaType == "PICTURE") {
      params["image_url"] = mediaUrl;
      if(tags != null) {
        params["user_tags"] = user_tags;
      }      
    } else if (mediaType == "VIDEO") {
      params["video_url"] = mediaUrl;
      params["media_type"] = "VIDEO";
    } else {
      reject({ message: "Unknow media!" });
      return;
    }
    axios
      .post(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/${instagramAccountId}/media`,
        params
      )
      .then(async (response) => {
        const container_id = response.data.id;
        let container_status = "IN_PROGRESS";
        while (container_status == "IN_PROGRESS") {
          container_status = await getContainerStatus(
            container_id,
            accessToken
          );
          console.log(container_status, "Container status");
        }
        // resolve(response.data);
        if (container_status == "ERROR") {
          reject({ error: "Container error!" });
        } else {
          resolve(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

/**
 * publish Instagram Media Object.
 * @param {string} accessToken user access token.
 * @param {string} instagramAcctId instagram media object creation id.
 * @param {string} mediaObjectId instagram media object creation id.
 * @return {Promise} Returns the Instagram Account Profile.
 */
function publishMedia(accessToken, instagramAcctId, mediaObjectId) {
  console.log(accessToken, " --> ", instagramAcctId, " --> ", mediaObjectId);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .post(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/${instagramAcctId}/media_publish`,
        {
          access_token: accessToken,
          creation_id: mediaObjectId,
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  }); 
}

/**
 * Facebook Login with uuid
 * body params {uuid, accessToken}
 */
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const uuid = req.body.uuid;
  const accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
  const instagramAccts = [];
  let longLiveToken, userData, pages;
  try {
    longLiveToken = await getLongLiveToken(accessToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "Failed to create LongLive Token",
    });
  }

  try {
    userData = await getFacebookProfile(accessToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "Failed to get Facebook profile",
    });
  }

  try {
    pages = await getFacebookPages(accessToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "Failed to get Facebook pages",
    });
  }

  if (pages.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      try {
        const data = await getInstagramAccountId(accessToken, pages[i].id);
        if (!data.error) {
          const igProfile = await getInstagramProfile(accessToken, data.id);
          // const tags = await db
          //   .collection("tags")
          //   .where("tag", igProfile["username"])
          //   .get();

          // if (tags.docs.length < 1) {
          //   await db.collection("tags").add({
          //     tag: igProfile["username"],
          //   });
          // }
          igProfile["isActive"] = true;
          if (i == 0) {
            igProfile["isPrimary"] = true;
          } else {
            igProfile["isPrimary"] = false;
          }
          instagramAccts.push(igProfile);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Failed to get Instagram accounts",
        });
      }
    }
  }

  try {
    await db.collection("users").doc(uuid).set({
      longLiveToken: longLiveToken,
      picture: userData.picture,
      name: userData.name,
      email: userData.email,
      facebookUserId: userData.facebookUserId,
      accessToken: accessToken,
      uuid: uuid,
      instagramAccts: instagramAccts,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "Failed to save user info to firestore",
    });
  }

  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Success",
    instagramAccts: instagramAccts,
  });
});

app.post("/getInstagramAccounts", async (req, res) => {
  const uuid = req.body.uuid;
  const user = await db.collection("users").doc(uuid).get();
  const userData = user.data();
  const accessToken = userData.longLiveToken;
  const instagramAccts = [];
  let pages;

  try {
    pages = await getFacebookPages(accessToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "Failed to get Facebook pages",
    });
  }

  if (pages.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      try {
        const data = await getInstagramAccountId(accessToken, pages[i].id);
        if (!data.error) {
          const igProfile = await getInstagramProfile(accessToken, data.id);
          if (i == 0) {
            igProfile["isActive"] = true;
          } else {
            igProfile["isActive"] = false;
          }
          instagramAccts.push(igProfile);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Failed to get Instagram accounts",
        });
      }
    }
  }
  try {
    await db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uuid)
      .update({ instagramAccts: instagramAccts });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: "Failed to update instagram accounts",
    });
  }
  return res.status(200).json({ instagramAccts: instagramAccts });
});

/**
 * Schedule Instagram Media Object to publish.
 * body params {time, mediaType, uuid, media, instagramAcctId}
 */
app.post("/schedule", async (req, res) => {
  const uuid = req.body.uuid;
  const time = req.body.time;
  const mediaType = req.body.mediaType;
  const media = req.body.media; // url string array
  const tags = req.body.tags; // array of strings
  const longitude = req.body.longitude;
  const latitude = req.body.latitude;
  const instagramAcctId = req.body.instagramAcctId;
  const caption = req.body.caption;
  const thumbnail = req.body.thumbnail;
  const timeStamp = req.body.timeStamp;
  const notificationIdentifier = req.notificationIdentifier;

  try {
    const postData = await db.collection("posts").add({
      uuid: uuid,
      time: time,
      mediaType: mediaType,
      media: media,
      instagramAcctId: instagramAcctId,
      published: false,
      caption: caption,
      tags: tags ? tags : null,
      thumbnail: thumbnail ? thumbnail : null,
      longitude: longitude,
      latitude: latitude,
      timeStamp: timeStamp,
      notificationIdentifier: notificationIdentifier ? notificationIdentifier : null,

    });
    const ref = await postData.get();
    await db.collection("posts").doc(ref.id).update({ id: ref.id });
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Success!",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});

app.post("/update-schedule", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  const time = req.body.time;
  const tags = req.body.tags; // array of strings
  const longitude = req.body.longitude;
  const latitude = req.body.latitude;
  const instagramAcctId = req.body.instagramAcctId;
  const caption = req.body.caption;
  const timeStamp = req.body.timeStamp;
  const notificationIdentifier  = req.body.notificationIdentifier;
  const updateData = {};
  if (time) {
    updateData["time"] = time;
  }
  if (tags) {
    updateData["tags"] = tags;
  }
  if (longitude) {
    updateData["longitude"] = longitude;
  }
  if (latitude) {
    updateData["latitude"] = latitude;
  }
  if (instagramAcctId) {
    updateData["instagramAcctId"] = instagramAcctId;
  }
  if (caption) {
    updateData["caption"] = caption;
  }
  if (timeStamp) {
    updateData["timeStamp"] = timeStamp;
  }
  if (notificationID) {
      updateData["notificationIdentifier"] = notificationIdentifier;
  }

  try {
    await db.collection("posts").doc(id).update(updateData);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Update success!",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});

app.post("/remove-schedule", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;

  try {
    const postData = await db.collection("posts").doc(id).get();
    if (postData.exists) {
      await db.collection("posts").doc(id).delete();
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Remove success!",
      });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: "There is no such post!",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});

app.post("/get-posts-by-date", async (req, res) => {
  const uuid = req.body.uuid;
  let posts_by_date = [];
  try {
    const posts = await db
      .collection("posts")
      .where("published", "==", false)
      .where("uuid", "==", uuid)
      .orderBy("time")
      .get();
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.docs.length; i++) {
      const postData = posts.docs[i].data();
      console.log(new Date(postData["time"]).toLocaleDateString());
      const localDate = new Date(postData["time"]).toLocaleDateString();
      if (posts_by_date[localDate]) {
        posts_by_date[localDate].push(postData);
      } else {
        posts_by_date[localDate] = [];
        posts_by_date[localDate].push(postData);
      }
    }
    console.log(posts_by_date, "posts by date");
    return res.status(200).json({
      posts: posts_by_date,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("* * * * *")
  .onRun((context) => {
    console.log("This will be run every 1 minute!");
    db.collection("posts")
      .where("published", "==", false)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          const post = doc.data();
          const now = new Date();
          const publishDate = new Date(post.time);
          if (publishDate <= now) {
            //publish media object.
            const uuid = post.uuid;
            const userRef = await db.collection("users").doc(uuid).get();
            const user = userRef.data();
            const longLiveToken = user.longLiveToken;
            const instagramAcctId = post.instagramAcctId;
            const medias = post.media;
            //const notificationIdentifier = post.notificationIdentifier;

            for (let i = 0; i < medias.length; i++) {
              try {
                const mediaObjects = await createInstagramMedia(
                  longLiveToken,
                  instagramAcctId,
                  post.caption,
                  post.mediaType,
                  medias[i],
                  post.tags,
                 // notificationIdentifier
                );
                const mediaObjectId = mediaObjects.id;
                await publishMedia(
                  longLiveToken,
                  instagramAcctId,
                  mediaObjectId
                );
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
              }
            }
            await db
              .collection("posts")
              .doc(doc.id)
              .update({ published: true });
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });

    return null;
  });

main.use("/v1", app);
main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(main);
```

and this is how the data is sent:

```
private func schedulePost(uuid: String, time: Date, mediaType: String, media: [String], caption: String, tags:[String], location: CLLocation?, thumbImageUrl: String) {
       
       var newCap: [String] = []
       newCap.append(caption)
       newCap.insert(contentsOf: tags, at: newCap.endIndex)
       let newCaption = newCap.joined(separator: " ")
       print (newCaption)
       
       AuthManager.shared.loadUser()
       guard let instagramAccountId = AuthManager.shared.currentUser?.id else {return}
       let timeStamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
       if !self.TrueStory {
           StoryManager().addNewTask("POST", "Post", time, self.ImageURL)
           print("Scheduled Post" + self.ImageURL)
         //  let notificationID = notificationIdentifier
           //tags.insert(caption, at: tags.firstIndex)
           let param = ["uuid": uuid, "time": time, "mediaType": mediaType, "media": media, "instagramAcctId": instagramAccountId, "caption": newCaption, "tags": "", "latitude": location?.coordinate.latitude ?? "", "longitude":location?.coordinate.longitude ?? "", "thumbnail":thumbImageUrl, "timeStamp":timeStamp, "notificationIdentifier":notificationIdentifier] as [String : Any]
           print ("The PARAMS are: ")
           print (param)
           ServerApi.shared.scheduleIGPosts(param: param, success: {response in
               print(response)
               ProgressHUD.dismiss()
               AppManager.shared.isPostScheduled = true
               AppManager.shared.showNext()
           //  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .PostWasSuccessfullyScheduled, object: nil, userInfo: ["posted": true])
               
           }, failure: {(error) in
               print(error)
               self.showAlert(error.description)
               ProgressHUD.dismiss()
           })
       } else if self.TrueStory {
           StoryManager().addNewTask("STORY", "Story", time, self.ImageURL)
           print("Scheduled Story" + self.ImageURL)
          // let notificationID = notificationIdentifier
           let param = ["uuid": uuid, "time": time, "mediaType": mediaType, "media": media, "instagramAcctId": instagramAccountId, "caption": caption, "tags": "", "latitude": location?.coordinate.latitude ?? "", "longitude":location?.coordinate.longitude ?? "", "thumbnail":thumbImageUrl, "timeStamp":timeStamp, "notificationIdentifier":notificationIdentifier] as [String : Any]
           // "notificationID":notificationIdentifier
           ServerApi.shared.scheduleIGPosts(param: param, success: {response in
               print(response)
               ProgressHUD.dismiss()
               AppManager.shared.isPostScheduled = true
               AppManager.shared.showNext()
            //   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .PostWasSuccessfullyScheduled, object: nil, userInfo: ["posted": true])
               
           }, failure: {(error) in
               print(error)
               self.showAlert(error.description)
               ProgressHUD.dismiss()
           })
       }
     
   }
```

And the "ScheduleIGPost" function for your entertainment:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
struct AppUrls {
    static let baseUrl = URL that I wont disclose
    static let registerIGAccounts = baseUrl + "register"
    static let scheduleIGPosts = baseUrl + "schedule"
    static let updateIGPosts = baseUrl + "update-schedule"
    static let removeIGPosts = baseUrl + "remove-schedule"
}
class ServerApi {
    static let shared = ServerApi()

  func scheduleIGPosts(param: [String: Any], success: @escaping(JSON) -> Void, failure: @escaping(JSON) -> Void) {
        ApiWrapper.requestPOSTURLWithoutToken(AppUrls.scheduleIGPosts, params: param, success: {(response) in
            print(JSON(response))
            success(JSON(response))
        }, failure: { (error) in
            let err = JSON(error)
            print(err)
            failure(err)
        })
    }
```

I did check and see if "param" included "notificationIdentifier" when sending to GCF and it does, but if I check the logs in GCF, I can see everything that's supposed to be except for "notificationIdentifier". And when I replace, for example, "tags" with the "notificationIdentifier", then it works.

I'm unsure if Firestore/Firebase has a limit of elements or not and why this behaviour is happening. To be honest, I couldn't find much information online.

Feel free to ask any questions if I was unclear, as I tend to be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved quite simply, the app is using a Cloud Function called "API" which is used before accessing the "Schedule" function. So changed the values (or rather added the values) and everything is working fine now.